# Lock layer effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How do I 'lock' layer effects? In that, when I rotate the layer, the fx rotates with it.

Currently, when I rotate a layer, the fx I have applied (a gradient) doesn't rotate with the layer, resulting in an odd look. Don't want to rasterize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a smart object of the layer.

Right/Control-Click on the Layer and Choose Convert to Smart Object. That will lock in the effects with the layer and allow them both to be transformed regardless fo the global light setting.